# EditText not focussing on touch

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, user-input

My EditText looks like:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/uuidInput"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

However, when I run my app, the EditText does not get focus on touch I dont know why.

I have a layout file `beacon_data_input.xml` which is included inside `activity_main.xml`

Here is my input view `beacon_data_input.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Beacon UUID:"/>
        <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="* "
            android:textColor="@color/red" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/uuidInput"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Beacon Major:"/>
        <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="* "
            android:textColor="@color/red"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/majorInput"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Beacon Minor:"/>
        <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="* "
            android:textColor="@color/red"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/minorInput"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml` includes the above layout as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

    <include layout="@layout/beacon_data_input" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/proximityRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedButton
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/StartButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#292d2e"
        android:textColor="#48c68f"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Start"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use android:focusableInTouchMode="true" or request focus when touch  edittext

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work

Comment: You can try this Edittxt.setFocusable(true);
               Edittxt.setCursorVisible(true);
            Edittxt.requestFocusFromTouch();   set in xml                                        android:cursorVisible="false"

Comment: @AyushGupta Please post your entire xml layout

Comment: not working, it is focused on first load but if I close the keyboard I cant open it again... and it's happening for 3 EditTexts

Comment: Are you try to hide some keyboard hide functionality on touch on other views? Check on this.

Comment: added the layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EditText is not getting touch because in `activity_main.xml` file, its getting overlap by `RecyclerView` & `LinearLayout`..

Try to put it like following (Add your `edittextLayout` over of each layout):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:id="@+id/proximityRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <com.nicbit.proximitydemo.common.customviews.RobotoCondensedButton
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/StartButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#292d2e"
            android:textColor="#48c68f"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Start"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>

<!--- Add them in last -->

        <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

        <include layout="@layout/beacon_data_input" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

or try after setting the visibility of that `RecyclerView` & `RobotoCondensedButton's`  & `LinearLayout's` visibility GONE.

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

add this line in your menifest in your activity.